# Convert back a projet to a simple folder in Powerdesigner

Tags: powerdesigner

In my repository I have a folder containing some physical models. I accidently clicked on "Convert to a project" which converted the folder to a project and now my folder is a project and have a different Icon (A briefcase Icon instead of a folder Icon).

How can I switch back the project to a simple folder, is there an option to convert back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking back at this question with PowerDesigner 16.6, there still isn't an option to undo the conversion.

However, you can create a new folder, and move the models under it...